# How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Limpet-Style Metal Superbones

Tags: biology, creature-design, chemistry, biochemistry, bio-mechanics

Some context, right off the bat: I am a mad scientist. This means that evolution has been [defenestrated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestration); as such, I am not interested in determining what evolutionary pressures might lead to the adoption of such a material as a supportive structure, and nor am I interested in where this thing might find aluminum to keep its bones intact; we're talking mad science and the limits of what's possible within the laws of physics and mortal biology here, not boring old evolution.

I, being a mad scientist, just so happen to be planning on making a creature with aluminum bones; specifically, bones whose primary material is [aluminum oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide), rather than carbonated [hydroxyapatite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroxyapatite).

Now, before we get any further, the question: **What are some structural or biological weaknesses of using aluminum oxide monocrystaline whiskers suspended in a collagen matrix as a material for bones - i.e., why shouldn't I?**

Please note that the core of these bones is plain 'ol [bone marrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_marrow). You gotta have that to live if you're Earthly life; I might be a mad scientist, but I'm not a *mad* scientist, y'know?

However, the other parts of these bones - i.e. where there would normally be carbonated hydroxyapatite - are made of aluminum oxide. Here's why that's great:

### [Aluminum oxide has several properties that make it superior to bone as a supportive structure.](https://www.azom.com/properties.aspx?ArticleID=52)

- A [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus) - how hard it is to deform - of 137 to 324 gigapascals, as opposed to [bone's average of 18.6 gigapascals](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8429054/).
- A [compressive strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressive_strength) - how much stress it can withstand before it deforms - of 690 megapascals to 5.5 gigapascals, as opposed to [bone's 170 megapascals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone#:%7E:text=Because%20of%20the%20way%20that,stress%20strength%20(51.6%20MPa).).
- An [endurance limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_limit) - the maximum strength of a [loading cycle](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/loading+cycles) (a repetitive stress) it can withstand indefinitely - of 59 to 488 megapascals, as opposed to bone's [23 to 30 megapascals](https://www.proquest.com/docview/235100769?pq-origsite=gscholar&fromopenview=true).
- A [hardness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardness) - how difficult it is to be dented or abraded - of [2600-2720 kg/mm/mm](https://www.memsnet.org/material/aluminumoxideal2o3bulk/), as opposed to [bone's low tens range](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31037844/.).
- A [modulus of rupture](https://www.instron.com/en-us/our-company/library/glossary/m/modulus-of-rupture?region=North%20America&lang=en-US) - that is, the maximum amount of stress each fiber of it can withstand right before it fails - of 152 to 800 megapascals. I cannot find a source for bone's modulus of rupture. However, [it is likely to be within the range of 104 to 121 megapascals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_properties_of_biomaterials#Fatigue) - around its [tensile strength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_tensile_strength) - since it is a relatively homogeneous material, and, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexural_strength#Flexural_versus_tensile_strength), this means that its tensile strength is likely comparable to, if potentially less than, its flexural strength. I would [handwave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-waving#In_literary_criticism) this, since I might be inaccurate here for lack of a source, but I actually have a solution to it below, and, at the very least, bone and aluminum oxide are likely *comparable* in terms of their modului of rupture; aluminum oxide is *probably* stronger.
- A [shear modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_modulus) - i.e. how resistant it is to being deformed sideways - of 88 to 165 gigapascals, as opposed to [bone's stupidly low 51.6 megapascals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone#:%7E:text=Because%20of%20the%20way%20that,stress%20strength%20(51.6%20MPa).).
- A tensile strength (as mentioned above) of 69 to 665 megapascals, as opposed to bone's [101-124 megapascals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone#:%7E:text=Because%20of%20the%20way%20that,stress%20strength%20(51.6%20MPa)). While this could potentially be less than that of bone, [let's assume it isn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hand-waving#In_literary_criticism), since the higher end of aluminum oxide's tensile strength is significantly higher than the high end of bone's.
- A [Young's modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus) - how stiff it is against lengthwise force - of 215 to 413 gigapascals, as opposed to bone's ~1 gigapascal; while I do not have a *direct* source for that figure, [the ratio of Young's modulus to the shear modulus of bone is 20:1](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/8920251/), and 20 * [51.6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone#:%7E:text=Because%20of%20the%20way%20that,stress%20strength%20(51.6%20MPa).) = 1,032.
- An [elastic modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_modulus) - how much force it can take before it non-permanently deforms - of [275 gigapascals (even at a relatively low concentration of 90%, i.e. 10% of it isn't aluminum oxide)](https://www.sonelastic.com/en/fundamentals/tables-of-materials-properties/ceramics.html) as opposed to bone's [34.11 gigapascals](http://shorturl.at/gyK03). Note that the elastic *modulus* is different from the elastic *limit* I mention below; the elastic *modulus* is related to *non-permanent* deformation, whereas the elastic *limit* is related to *permanent* deformation.

Now, as I mentioned further up this post, it might seem that aluminum oxide has a few glaring weaknesses in comparison to bone; it likely has a lesser ductility and elastic limit, and I had to handwave its fracture toughness and Poisson's ratio.

While I cannot find figures on the [elastic limit](https://www.britannica.com/science/elastic-limit) - how much force per unit of area it can withstand without *being permanently deformed* - and [ductility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ductility) - how much it can be [elastically deformed](https://www.corrosionpedia.com/definition/2104/elastic-deformation) without *fracturing* - I'm willing to bet that bone's elastic limit is greater than aluminum oxide's elastic limit of 69 to 665 megapascals, and that bone's ductility is greater than aluminum oxide's ductility of of 0.00018.

The only relevant areas in which I know for a fact that it's possible for bone to beat aluminum oxide are [fracture toughness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_toughness) - how hard it is for an already-established crack in the substance to grow further - and [Poisson's ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%27s_ratio) - how much a substance squishes out to the sides when compressed.

- [Cortical bone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone#Cortex) has a fracture toughness of [2 to 12 MPa.m^(-1/2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_properties_of_biomaterials#Fatigue), whereas aluminum oxide has a fracture toughness of 3.3 to 5 MPa.m^(-1/2). This is enough for a handwave.
- Cortical bone also has a [Poisson's ratio](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/10.1121/1.2935440) of [0.12 to 0.63](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002192900600039X#:%7E:text=Few%20studies%20describe%20experimental%20determination,ranged%20between%200.29%20and%200.63.) (if you want to find that particular bit, use control-F to find it, since it's a long source), as opposed to aluminum oxide's 0.21 to 0.33, meaning that aluminum oxide might be squishier. Again, a handwave is completely possible here, but these things will become irrelevant once I implement my solution to aluminum oxide's flexibility and brittleness problems below.

I have a solution to these things, you see; you structure the aluminum oxide bones like [limpet teeth](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-31500883). Limpet teeth contain [monocrystalline whiskers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocrystalline_whisker) of [goethite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goethite) - that is, crystals of goethite that are so small that they're flaw-insensitive, meaning that they do not have structural impurities that make larger crystals more susceptible to structural failures.  Moreover - and this is the important point - these goethite crystals are embedded in a matrix of [collagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collagen), which allows the teeth of a limpet to be flexible, non-brittle, etc.

In addition to that, these goethite crystals have a low critical fiber length relative to their total, meaning that they're very good at transferring loads to the collagen matrix - in other words, they don't need to be very long to act as good shock absorbers.

My solution to this, therefore, is to suspend crystals/fibers of aluminum oxide within a collagen matrix - much like a limpet's teeth are crystals/fibers of [iron(III) oxide-hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_oxide-hydroxide) (goethite) within a collagen matrix - to bring the flexibility of these bones up to a level more comparable to more conventional Earthly life.

All in all, *I'd* say that aluminum oxide monocrystalline whiskers suspended within a collagen matrix are - mechanically speaking, at least - a much better bone than the ones that actually exist in real life, but of course I'd say that, because I came up with 'em. It remains to be seen whether there are *actually* problems with them, which is where you come in:

**What are some structural or biological weaknesses of using aluminum oxide monocrystaline whiskers suspended in a collagen matrix as a material for bones - i.e., why shouldn't I?**

Assume that this creature with aluminum oxide bones is designed to operate under "normal" Earth-standard conditions, on land, at sea level, etc, and that, other than its unique supportive structures, it is essentially a tiger in all other aspects of its biology.

**Good answers will point out a problem with these types of bones, and have a sense of biology, physics, and chemistry at least as strong as my rudimentary ones.**

**Here are three answers that I already have solutions for, *and that I would not like people to answer with*:**

1. Weight. Aluminum oxide is 3.95 grams/cm^3, whereas bone is ~0.92-1.4 grams/cm^3. These bones will be ~2.75-4 times heavier per unit of mass. I know this, and have found a way around it.
2. Availability. Aluminum has to be extracted from substances like [bauxite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauxite), and new metabolic pathways need to be developed to process and handle it. I know this, and have found a way around it.
3. Toxicity. [Aluminum oxide fibers are apparently bad for you](https://wayback.archive-it.org/all/20080522232533/http://www.epa.gov/tri/chemical/chemical%20lists/RY2006ChemicalList.pdf); I personally imagine that they're an inhalant risk, but have no hard sources on that. I don't consider this a problem, for various reasons outside of the scope of this question; i.e. toxic bones are ***awesome***.

I was inspired by [Logan R. Kearsley's answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/218813/87100) to [a previous question of mine](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/218772/87100).

Comment: What're the dimensions of the fibres, the patterns of distribution? Here's a picture of how a [bone is constructed](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Schematic-illustration-of-the-basic-microstructure-of-a-cortical-bone_fig2_300780289) to optimise for various factors, not the least of which is blood circulation. How are your bones optimised?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Blood circulation was something I was going to handwave until later, but now that you've brought the structure of the bone up, I imagine that it would be similar to that image, except for having thinner bone exterior walls/compact bone, since the material making them would be stronger, requiring less volume for the same effectiveness. This would let both the spongy bone and bone marrow cavity take up the remaining space. As for the dimensions of the fibers and their pattern of distribution, it's whatever's the most optimal, whatever that is.

Comment: Imagine picking a car and swapping out its crumple zone for a nigh indestructible material and then claiming the car is safer for it. Our bones break when they do for protection. For humans Its easier to survive and heal a bone than it is to survive and heal an organ like a liver, lung or perhaps shattered bloodvessles. The breaking absorbs kinetic energy that would otherwise damage more important organs. You would need some kind of composite material that can both break but partially remain intact for structure somehow.

Comment: @Demigan In that case, imagine that a layer of non-whiskered aluminum oxide surrounds the rest of it; unlike the other aluminum oxide, which has been turned into monocrystaline whiskers inside a collagen matrix, this aluminum oxide is by itself, and therefore brittle enough to break.

Comment: Similarly, an elastic modulus helps to absorb shocks.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE "Aluminum hydroxide's lack of an ..." Aluminium hydroxide and aluminium oxide are two different substances (and both different from the [aluminium oxyhydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_hydroxide_oxide))

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Sorry, my thinking bits are parched. I'll re-write that comment. I never mentioned aluminum oxyhydroxide, though.

Comment: @Anon Aluminum oxide's lack of an elastic modulus is resolved in this case by putting it inside a collagen matrix; it's not one solid piece, but a bunch of little pieces in a semi-flexible sheath of protein.

Comment: Might run into integrity issues if it's not one solid piece, and your whole structure would only then be as strong as the connective tissues, which as far as I know won't be much if collagen is anything to go by

Comment: @Lemming Nope - that's why I structured them like limpet teeth. It's more like stiff chain mail made of tiny little fibers of aluminum oxide with collagen linking each piece.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE "I never mentioned aluminum oxyhydroxide, though." Too bad. I think there's a reason for which aluminium oxides occurs rarely as minerals in nature and, when they do, is either metamophic or ultramafic geologies, _most_ of the other aluminium minerals being a hydrated form of aluminium (even in silicates). Can you guess what that reason is and how it has relevance in the context of your question?

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi No, I can't guess what that is. As I said, I have a rudimentary knowledge of chemistry; this post's vague accuracy is a result of me using up a lot of free time per day to counteract that. I should point out that this creature does not consume (as you pointed out, rare) oxides of aluminum; its options are wider, in that all it needs to do is intake some kind of aluminum and react it with oxygen. I have a plan for this, which I covered under "Availability"; since I made this post, it has evolved to be more specific - something involving gibbsite and repurposed parietal cells.

Comment: @Demigan: A wild animal that breaks a bone is likely to starve to death from being unable to find food.  Bit hard to argue that that's an advantage.

Comment: @Vikki wild animals dont have this feature. However humans do, healing bones is pretty much one of our superpowers (because our social structure allows us to not starve). And like almost every biological feature its used for as many purposes as possible. Like calcium storage, or since we can actually survive a broken bone to absorb shocks and safeguard more important organs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In hydrated environs, aluminium will form preferably [its hydroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_hydroxide)

To get it to form aluminium oxide, one needs to calcine it as high as  [1100C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_oxide#Production). This is why one will find the crystalline form of [aluminium oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corundum) mainly in geologies which had some way or another to do with heating and pressure (metamorphic or ultramafic). If you get to volcanic rocks, it will be mainly associated with various forms of silicates (together with other metals).

In the context of the question - I doubt you'll find a biochemistry path able to convince aluminium hydroxides to part with their beloved water and be happy with the oxygen only - you simply need too much energy.

Comment: "you simply need too much energy"? I smell a challenge. However, IIRC, you can also react aluminum hydroxide with hydrochloric acid to turn it into aluminum chloride and water, and then turn that into aluminum oxide and hydrochloric acid - hence my comment about gibbsite and repurposed parietal cells. +1 anyway.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE "aluminum hydroxide with hydrochloric acid to turn it into aluminum chloride and water". Surprise! It won't work.  The only route you can prepare [anhydrous AlCl3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_chloride#Anhydrous) is by [directly burning aluminium in chlorine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aK85PZX2xNE). The moment you let water get into the picture, the [anhydrous AlCl3 hydrolyzes spontaneously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium_chloride#Reactions_with_water), forming HCl and aluminium hydroxide. That is to say: Al is happier with 3 OH than with 3 Cl. (ctnd)

Comment: (ctnd) Sure, you can dissolve Al directly in an aqueous solution HCl, what you'll get is $Al(H_{2}O)_{6}Cl_3$. Which is impossible to get dehydrated by simple heating, as it goes on the path of $Al(H_2O)_6Cl_3 → Al(OH)_3 + 3 HCl + 3 H_2O$. You need dry conditions and other substances [melted together at 150C+](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4493784A/en) to recover _some_ anhydrous AlCl3